# (nuxt3): v-bind in css not applied on initial render

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have created a component that is mostly visual, but I wanted to allow for different options, so it can be reused in different places.

I used v-bind in the css to allow for different options. Problem is that it seems to not be applied on the initial render. Is there a way that I can achieve that?

In the example below, the header will be black on the initial render and a little while later it turns red. Is there a way for it to make it red already on the initial render?

```html
<template>
  <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{ color?: string }>(), { color: 'red' })
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: v-bind(color);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Is it the same if you use it like this: ``<h1 :style="`color: ${color}`">Hello World</h1>``

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a possible workaround is to pass css variables through the style property:

```html
<template>
  <h1 :style="cssVars">Hello world!</h1>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{ color?: string }>(), { color: 'red' })
const cssVars = {
  '--color': 'red'
}
</script>

<style scoped>
h1 {
  color: var(--color);
}
</style>
```

Comment: v-bind can use if you don't want to use inline styles. this solution still use inline style :(